# Using Zod with existing typescript interface

Tags: typescript, grpc, zod

I have an API with generated typescript types/interfaces. As with many APIs I need to change the data structure to something more convenient in frontend. Partily it is to flatted the structure, and rename clunky names, but more importantly, the generated types includes a lot of fields marked as optional which I know will be present.

```
type GeneratedAction = {
  id: string;
  description: string;
  recordsList?: GeneratedRecordsList[];
};
type GeneratedRecordsList = {
  timestamp: { epochMillis: number };
  traceId: string;
  code?: string;
  responseTimeMs: number;
  fullId?: { someId: string; otherId: string };
};
```

What I want is something like this:

```
interface SelfTypedAction {
  id: string;
  description: string;
  recordsList: SelfTypedRecordsList[];
}

export interface SelfTypedRecordsList {
  timestamp: number;
  code: string;
  responseTimeMs: number;
  someId: string;
  otherId: string;
}
```

So far I've used this function to convert the data:

```
const convertToObject = (action: GeneratedAction): SelfTypedAction => {
  return {
    ...action,
    recordsList: action.recordsList.map(record => {
      return {
        ...record,
        someId: record.fullId?.someId!, //I know that this will always be defined
        otherId: record.fullId?.otherId!, //I know that this will always be defined
        code: record.code!, //I know that this will always be defined
        timestamp: record.timestamp?.epochMillis || 0
      };
    })
  };
};
```

I tried to convert this into a zod-schema because the optional-stuff is so clunky, as well as using the !-operator is something I try avoid doing.

```
export const ZodRecordsList = z.object({
  timestamp: z.number().default(0),
  code: z.string(),
  responseTimeMs: z.number(),
  someId: z.string(),
  otherId: z.string()
});

export const ZodAction = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  description: z.string(),
  recordsList: z.array(ZodRecordsList)
});
export type ZodActionType = z.infer<typeof ZodAction>;

const convertToObjectZod = (action: GeneratedAction): ZodActionType => {
  return ZodAction.parse({
    ...action,
    recordsList: action.recordsList.map(record => {
      return ZodRecordsList.parse({
        ...record,
        someId: record.fullId?.someId,
        otherId: record.fullId?.otherId,
        timestamp: record.timestamp?.epochMillis
      });
    })
  });
};
```

I don't think this is much of an improvement. It might be that is is possible to make the conversion go easier with transform, or other zod-features. However as far as I can see this really creates another problem. If something changes in the generated types. For example description is removed, I would not get an error until runtime. While my original code would give me this as soon as the generated types where changed. Are there any way to spot errors in generated types immediately and still make conversion go easier? The real code has a lot more deeper structures than this sample.

CodePen playground: https://codepen.io/MrMamen/pen/QWopZBp

Comment: I may have misunderstood your use case, but it sounds like you want the `Required<T>` utility type.

Comment: Or maybe DeepRequired... `export type DeepRequired<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Required<DeepRequired<T[K]>>
}`

Comment: See https://tsplay.dev/N7GarN